# Combination formula: n-1 choose -1

Tags: induction, combinations

This is actually a question involving the recurrence relation in binomial coefficient formula, which is $${n \choose k} = {n-1 \choose k-1} + {n-1 \choose k}$$.

I am trying to prove this formula by induction and I know the proof is valid. However, when I am trying to set up the base case, I am setting n and k to both 0. (I know in math natural number starts from 1, but here 0 is required to be in natural numbers due to restriction).

The problem I feel confused is that when I set n = k = 0, I know $${0 \choose 0} = 1$$

However, in this case, the RHS will be equal to 2 instead of 1, which causes the base case to fail.

I ask this question to my professor, my professor told me that: $${n-1 \choose -1} = 0$$

Why is this so? I feel so confused, I google that the factorial of -1  is equal to some complex number, which I don't know, I have no idea the above identity holds.

Can someone help figure out my confusion?

P.S. 0 must be in natural numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "...but here 0 is required to be in natural numbers due to restriction". Pascal's identity is valid for natural n and k, so there's no reason to start at n = k = 0. Your base case should be for n = k = 1, i.e. $\binom{1}{1} = \binom{0}{0} + \binom {0}{1}$; no negative values need be involved.

Answer (score 1):

Oftentimes things in probability are defined in such a way out of convenience, but this time you're just misinterpreting what Pascal's rule applies to. This identity is true for values of $1\leq k\leq n$, but $k=0$ is not included.

Comment: This is just a practice question in my computer science course, so in this course, our professor specifically indicates that 0 belongs to natural number. So what I understand is that we need to prove base case induction first, that's why I say that it must starts from 0. Here is where my confusion kicks in, I have a little understanding with Pascal's triangle, after I plug n=k=0, I got the -1 mentioned above, and my professor told me that n-1 chooses -1 is equal to 0. That's why I feel so confused.

Comment: Your professor is just defining it that way it seems. Don't be confused over a definition. It's merely for convenience. But anyway, you still don't have to start with $0$. Starting with $n=1$, you show $P(1)$ is true, and then if your induction proof is successful, it means that the result follows for all $n \geq 1$. The only thing we don't know from this is whether or not it's true for $n=0$, but that's okay.